# how to bind the values from api in apex chart using angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular12, ng-apexcharts

I want to bind the values from api in apexchart area chart

app.comp.ts

```
salesforpurchase : result[]
 this.service.sales().subscribe (data=> {
      this.salesforpurchase=data.data
```

In result[] , values will be

date:2012-03-02,
sales:256

and so on...

```
 intializationChartoption():void {
    this.title ={
      text: 'linechart'
    };

  this.series = [{
         name: 'Purchase',
         data: [20,10,300] //static data . Here i want to bring sales value from result[]
       }]
     
      

    this.chart ={
      type: 'area',
      width :650,
      
    };
  }
```

html

```
<apx-chart [series]="series" [chart]="chart" [title]="title"
></apx-chart>
```

Please help me how to bind the data dynamically to apex chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to notice is to initialize the value within the subscription callback. In other words, you'd need to subscribe to the observable where it's response is required.

Second, to get only the `sales` property of each object of the array as it's own array, you could use the `Array#map` function.

Try the following

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.sales().subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      this.intializationChartoption(  // <-- this call *must* be inside the subscription callback
        data.map((item: any) => item.sales)
      );
    },
    error => {
      // handle errors
    }
  );
}

intializationChartoption(series: number[]): void {
  this.title ={
    text: 'linechart'
  };

  this.series = [{
    name: 'Purchase',
    data: series
  }];

  this.chart = {
    type: 'area',
    width :650,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: data=> {
      this.intializationChartoption(  // <-- this call *must* be inside the subscription callback
        data.map(item => item.sales)
      );
    },

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type') and also 

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sales')

Comment: @MohamedIrshath: You must defined corresponding types for the variables `data` and `type`. I've update the answer with type `any`.

Comment: @MohamedIrshath: On second thought, if the error says the variable is `undefined`, check (eg. using a `console.log`) if the emitted notification is of the form you're expecting.

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    const form = {
      fromdate: '2021-02-02',
      todate: '2021-10-02',
      ',
    };
    this.service.value(form).subscribe(
      data=> {
        if(data){
          this.intializationChartoption(data.data.map(x=>x.totalsales))
        }
      },
    );
  }
   intializationChartoption(series: number[]):void {
         this.title ={
      text: 'linechart'
    };
    this.series = [{
      name: 'Purchase',
      data: series  
    }]
    this.chart = {
      type: "area",
      stacked: false,
      height: 350,
    };
  }

Comment: I wrote this code but i m getting same error

Comment: You're checking if `data` is defined but aren't checking if `data.data` is defined

Comment: Please do a `console.log(data)` inside the subscription callback and post the screenshot.

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the question . @Michael D

Comment: I have resolved the type error by setting flag

Comment: I m upvoting this answer

Answer (score 0):

You would just have to update the series values and reasign it, so apex chart would detect changes on the series and try to update the chart.

I did a quick example on stackblitz randomizing the first value eveyr few seconds.
In your case, everytime you get a value from your api, you prepare you data accordinly and the reasign the series afterwards.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xkbqdb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: static data is working but dynamic data is not working. Could you please do it dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

1. First initialize the data as empty array so that we can show default chart in the view at first by calling this method in the constructor.

   ```
   intializationChartoption(): void {

   this.title ={
      text: 'linechart'
     };

   this.series = [{
     name: 'Purchase',
     data: []
     }];

   this.chart = {
      type: 'area',
      width :650,
      };
    }
   }
   ```
2. Call the intializationChartoption() in the component's constructor.

   ```
      constructor() {
             this.intializationChartoption();
      }
   ```
3. Subscribe the service on ngOnInit() so that whenever a component load, after the constructor it will be called. To fetch the sales data from the object array we can use map function.

   ```
      ngOnInit() {
           this.service.sales().subscribe((response: any) => {
               const data = response.data;
               this.series.data[0] = data.map((item:any) => item.sales) 
           });
       }
   ```
4. You can follow the same approach for x-axis and other series objects.